# Symfony 3 & Doctrine - Complex form with OnetoMany and ManyToMany relation

Tags: symfony-forms

I want to manage the rates of a product in multi-currency and keep historic of currency rates.

So onetomany relation:
A Rates can have many CurrencyRate.

A manyto many relation:
Many currencyRate have many currencies.

RATES :

```
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rate            | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timeStamp       | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| currencyRate_id | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

CURRENCY RATES

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rate      | double   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timeStamp | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

currencyrateshascurrencies (manytomany join table)

```
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| currency_id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| currencyRate_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

currencies

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| abreviation | varchar(5)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to generate a form from all of this.
The html form would get all available currencies with a text field to indicate the CurrencyRate.
Ex :

```
USD <input type="text">
EUR <input type="text">
CNY <input type="text">
...
```

I saw the documentation on Symfony about manytomany form. But mine is more complex with an additional onetomany relation and text field. I am totaly lost.

Thanks if you can put me on the right direction.

Best regards,

Pierre

Comment: Oula, I think I mixed everything's up. I do not need a manytomany relation I guess. Will correct myself soon

Answer (score 0):

I found the response :

First I needed to correct my Schema which didn't need a ManytoMany relation :

Rates :

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rate      | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timeStamp | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

CURRENCY RATES

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ratio       | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| currency_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Rate_id     | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Currencies

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| abreviation | varchar(5)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then One Form Type

```
class CurrencyRateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('currency',EntityType::class, array(
                                'class'=>'AppBundle:Currencies',
                                'choice_label' => 'abreviation',
                                'disabled' => true,
                 ))
                ->add('ratio', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => CurrencyRates::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

which is embedded in the final form type :

```
class RateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder    ->add('rate')
                    ->add('CurrencyRate', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => CurrencyRateType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false))
            )
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'create'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Rates::class,
        ));
    }
}
```